# Is it possible to make a bot limit the amount of a specific reaction on a specific message?

Tags: discord.js

My friend is creating an event where the first 24 people to react to their message are entered. Is there a way to make it so that after 24 reactions, a bot will remove any new reactions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just delete the message after. However what you can do is lock the permission to add new reactions, and clear all the reactions on that message so that no one can add new ones. If you're talking about wanting to keep the existing reactions. You can do this.

```js
<Client>.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => { //on reaction
  if(reaction.message.id == "you_reaction_message_id" && reaction.users.size >= 24) { //if the message is the right one, and if it's equal to or more than 24 users on that reaction.
    reaction.users.remove(user); //MASTER
    reaction.remove(user); //STABLE
  }
})
```

Again not the best idea but. It works.